# не присылаются cookie в запросе java

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, вначале куки вроде устанавливаются, но в метод ttt не передаются. Подскажите, в чем ошибка?

```
@Controller
    public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping("/qwe/{id}")
        public String qwe(@PathVariable("id") Integer id,
                HttpServletResponse response) {
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("buy", id.toString());
            cookie.setMaxAge(500);
            response.addCookie(cookie);
            return "redirect:/ttt";
        }

        @RequestMapping("/ttt")
        public ModelAndView ttt(ModelAndView model,
                @CookieValue(value = "buy") String cookie,
                HttpServletRequest request) {
            model.addObject("cookie", cookie);
            model.setViewName("view");
            return model;
        }
    }
```

view.jsp

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>${cookie}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

ошибка:

```
HTTP Status [400] – [Bad Request]
Missing cookie 'buy' for method parameter of type String
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

Comment: А Вы уверены, что браузер передает куку `buy` на сервер? Посмотрите в консоли браузера.

Comment: @MrFylypenko у меня ошибочка была, изменил  cookie.setMaxAge(500);, сейчас в консоле при обращении к методу qwe 
заголовок ответа
Set-Cookie 
"buy=4; Max-Age=500;

Comment: @MrFylypenko но при обращении к ttt этих куков уже нет,только JSESSIONID

Comment: Только что проверил, все работает. При переходе на `/qwe/{id}` куки задаются, и следующий запрос(редирект) браузера идет с этой кукой. А если напрямую обращаться к `/ttt` (после рестарта приложения, либо кука истекла, либо удалили ее), то возникает указанная ошибка.

Comment: @MrFylypenko спасибо,я решил проблему, в методе qwe написал cookie.setPath(корень проекта); и теперь всё работает хорошо.